# Insert an associative array into another associative array, maintaining keys

Tags: php, arrays, json

The function I have is below and the output of it.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tmsessions WHERE session_user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");

    $count = mysql_num_rows($results);
    $username = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT user_fname FROM tmusers WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'"));

    $json_data = array( 'userID'=>$_SESSION['user_id'], 'userName'=>$username['user_fname'], 'total'=>$count );

    while($session = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        $numListItems = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT session_id, listing_unique_id FROM tmdata WHERE session_id = '".$session['session_id']."'"));

        $listItems = array('sessionID'=>$session['session_id'],
                           'sessionName'=>$session['session_name'],
                           'sessionCount'=>$numListItems,
                           'sessionDC'=>date('h:iA - M m y',strtotime($session['session_date_created'])),
                           'sessionDM'=>date('h:iA - M m y',strtotime($session['session_date_modified'])),
                           'sessionActive'=>$session['session_active']);

        array_push($json_data, $listItems);

    }

    return json_encode($json_data);
```

Which outouts:

```
{"0":
{"sessionID":"9",
 "sessionName":"dataName0",
 "sessionCount":100,
 "sessionDC":"12:11AM - Jun 06 11",
 "sessionDM":"01:00AM - Jan 01 70",
 "sessionActive":"1"},
 "1":
{"sessionID":"10",
 "sessionName":"dataName1",
 "sessionCount":100,
 "sessionDC":"05:04PM - Jun 06 11",
 "sessionDM":"01:00AM - Jan 01 70",
 "sessionActive":"1"},
 "userID":"1",
 "userName":"Ezra",
 "total":2}
```

I need the "0": and "1": bits to become "listItem": of each new associative array, but I don't know howto manipulate the arrays correctly to get that :(.

Comment: You can't have them all named `listItem` as that would mean they all have the same key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, indexed and associative arrays are handled as the same type (i.e. matrices or one-dimensional arrays, a[0], a[1], ... a[N], vs a['one'], a['two'], ... a['something']).

When using array_push() you are not creating or adding to an associative hash, but an indexed value to the end of the array.

Instead of using the array_push() function, you could do a direct assignment with a name of your choice, e.g.

```
$listItems[$session['session_id']] = array('sessionID'=>$session['session_id'],
                           'sessionName'=>$session['session_name'],
                           'sessionCount'=>$numListItems,
                           'sessionDC'=>date('h:iA - M m y',strtotime($session['session_date_created'])),
                           'sessionDM'=>date('h:iA - M m y',strtotime($session['session_date_modified'])),
                           'sessionActive'=>$session['session_active']);
```

Comment: "Instead of using the array_push() function" What do you mean? I need the array_push funstion to get the while arrays into the $json_data array.

Comment: Using array_push() as you do, simply assigns data to the end of the array you give it, see my example code for directly assigning the data to an associative name of your choice.

Comment: That IS more like what I want.. but the way I understand it atm theres an error somewhere, see ->> http://pastie.org/2100043

Answer (score 1):

Try this if i understand your question correctly than its help you otherwise sorry and tell me what i understand wrong?

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tmsessions WHERE session_user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");

$count = mysql_num_rows($results);
$username = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT user_fname FROM tmusers WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'"));

$json_data = array( 'userID'=>$_SESSION['user_id'], 'userName'=>$username['user_fname'], 'total'=>$count );

while($session = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    $numListItems = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT session_id, listing_unique_id FROM tmdata WHERE session_id = '".$session['session_id']."'"));

    $listItems = array('sessionID'=>$session['session_id'],
                       'sessionName'=>$session['session_name'],
                       'sessionCount'=>$numListItems,
                       'sessionDC'=>date('h:iA - M m y',strtotime($session['session_date_created'])),
                       'sessionDM'=>date('h:iA - M m y',strtotime($session['session_date_modified'])),
                       'sessionActive'=>$session['session_active']);

    $json_data['listItem'][] = $listItems;
}

return json_encode($json_data);
```